Locked out of iPad
I am locked out of iPad due to forgotten password and I tried to many times, so it got security locked. Is there a way to get back in when I now know my Apple ID and password?

If you forgot the passcode to unlock the iPad, you will need to erase it and then set it up new or restore from a backup after it is restored.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/118107
https://support.apple.com/en-us/119858

The only other option is if you have a computer that the iPad trusted to sync content from before you locked it out, connecting it to that computer may unlock things without an erase or a restore.
Based on the comments here, start on the first link above, borrow any PC or Mac and erase the iPad.

I had forgotten it, but now I know it. Problem is that now it’s security locked, so I can’t put the password in.

I was wondering if I can remotely log back into iPad from another device? Now I know both Apple ID AND password.

Which exact iPad? Which iPadOS is running? (Or likely running) @MjaWeerasekara what exactly is on the screen when you plug it in to charge?

16.7.7 security locked out because I tried the password to many times. I have tried plugging into laptop with iTunes, this method, but it tells not enough space, so if this is the only option, then will need to wait until I can get to someone with a laptop with enough space to do the factory reset option.

If you can’t take it to a computer that the iPad trusts, you need to erase. There’s no other bypass from that state, so sorry.

Yes, but how to I erase when I can’t get into it? Is the iTunes, the only way to do this? OR can I log in with my ID and password from another iPad, or cell phone.

It’s step 1 in the first article under the heading Restore your device to factory settings but you need to fix your space issue on the computer first from the sounds of your comment above.

Okay thank you Mike. If I don’t care about saving information on iPad, can I use any laptop/computer to restore to factory setting?
